# Como scanear os IP de uma rede selecionada pelo usuario, e mostrar os que estão sendo usados e os que estao disponiveis, em ordem. PYTHON

Tags: python, ip

Olá, estou tentando desenvolver um programinha basico, para rodar tanto em linux quanto em WINDOWS, no qual eu consiga deixar o usuario escolher o ip inical e o final e mostre dentre todos da rede quais IPs ja estao sendo utilizados por alguma maquina e os que estão disponiveis.
para nao dar erros queria tbm que o usuario identificasse seu sistema operacional
exemplo:

```
print("Escolha seu sistema operacional")
print("(1) WINDOWS")
print("(2) LINUX")
print("(3) MAC")
print("(4) SAIR")

if == 1:
print("Digite o IP inicial")   exemplo digitado pelo usuario 192.168.254.1
i1= input()
print("Digite o IP Final")     exemplo digitado pelo usuario 192.168.254.254
i2 = input() 
nao sei como fazer isso para cada sistema
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx


if == 2:
print("Digite o IP inicial")   exemplo digitado pelo usuario 192.168.254.1
i1= input()
print("Digite o IP Final")     exemplo digitado pelo usuario 192.168.254.254
i2 = input() 
nao sei como fazer isso para cada sistema
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx

if == 3:
print("Digite o IP inicial")   exemplo digitado pelo usuario 192.168.254.1
i1= input()
print("Digite o IP Final")     exemplo digitado pelo usuario 192.168.254.254
i2 = input() 
nao sei como fazer isso para cada sistema
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não deve se preocupar com o sistema operacional no qual seu programa está sendo executado a não ser que você tenha um motivo **muito especial**!

`Python` é uma linguagem [portável](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portabilidade_(inform%C3%A1tica)) e a solução para o seu problema também pode ser.

Instalando biblioteca [`ping3`](https://github.com/kyan001/ping3) via `pip`:

```
$ pip install ping3
```

A ideia desta implementação é enviar um pacote [`ICMP`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) (vulgo [*ping*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping)) para cada endereço de IP dentro de uma faixa de IPs escolhida pelo usuário, isso vai nos permitir testar a conectividade de cada um deles, veja só:

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address
from ping3 import ping

inicial = IPv4Address(input("Digite o IP inicial: "))
final = IPv4Address(input("Digite o IP final: "))

ips = [str(IPv4Address(ip)) for ip in range(int(inicial), int(final))]

try:
    for ip in ips:
        t = ping(ip, timeout=5)
        status = 'OFFLINE' if t is None else 'ONLINE'
        print(f'IP: {ip} [{status}]')
except PermissionError:
    print('Usuario nao possui privilegios de Administrador!')
```

Testando:

```
Digite o IP inicial: 192.168.15.1
Digite o IP final: 192.168.15.10
IP: 192.168.15.1 [ONLINE]
IP: 192.168.15.2 [OFFLINE]
IP: 192.168.15.3 [ONLINE]
IP: 192.168.15.4 [ONLINE]
IP: 192.168.15.5 [ONLINE]
IP: 192.168.15.6 [OFFLINE]
IP: 192.168.15.7 [OFFLINE]
IP: 192.168.15.8 [OFFLINE]
IP: 192.168.15.9 [OFFLINE]
```

Se a detecção do sistema operacional é algo essencial no seu caso, você pode fazer isso de forma automática, sem a necessidade de questionar o usuário, usando o atributo [`sys.platform`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sys.html#sys.platform), por exemplo:

```
import sys

if sys.platform.startswith('linux'):
    print('Linux!')
elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    print('Windows!')
elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
    print('Mac OS')
else:
    print('Sistema Desconhecido!')
```

Comment: amigo, como eu coloco em uma interface grafica, mostrando os IPs offline de um lado e o ONLINE do outro